# How can I add Sum from another Table in my Model?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have my View setup like this in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult View(Guid projectID)
    {
        OnboardModel model = context.onboard_projectInfos.Where(x => x.projectID == projectID).Select(x =>
                                            new OnboardModel()
                                            {
                                                propertymanagername = x.propertymanagername,
                                                propertymanagercontactemail = x.propertymanagercontactemail,
                                                date_modified = (DateTime)x.date_modified,
                                                projectmanagercontactnumber = x.projectmanagercontactnumber,
                                                Developer = x.onboard_projectCreate.Developer,
                                                status1 = x.onboard_projectCreate.status1,
                                                ProjectName = x.onboard_projectCreate.ProjectName
                                            }).SingleOrDefault();


        var pix = projectID.ToString();
        context.onboard_BuildingInfos.Where(x => x.buildprojectID == pix).GroupBy(x => x.buildprojectID).Select(g => {
            model.totalres = g.Sum(b => b.numberofres);
            model.totalcom = g.Sum(b => b.numberofcommer);
        });

        return View(model);
    }
```

Problem is grabbing the sum of numberofres and numberofcommer from BuildingInfos. 
Using .Select gives me the error:

Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Queryable.Select(IQueryable, Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How to I write this LINQ statement correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify an object within a select (you can only create a new object). Further, you can't add new properties to an existing object.

We'll assume that `OnboardModel` defines the `totalres` and `totalcom` properties.

```
var query = context.onboard_BuildingInfos
                   .Where(x => x.buildprojectID == pix)
                   .GroupBy(x => x.buildprojectID);

foreach(var g in query)
{
        model.totalres = g.Sum(b => b.numberofres);
        model.totalcom = g.Sum(b => b.numberofcommer);
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, Thank you.